# API design for measure time spent in a function

Tags: c++, api-design

Which of the following API:s would be cleanest if you want a way of measuring the time spent in a particular Callable `f`, in terms of composability, ease-of-use, and clean callsite.

```
/** Calls `f` with args and returns a TimedResult carrying
* the return value of `f`, and the real time spent in `f`.
*/
template<class Function, class... T>
auto timedCall(Function&& f, T&&... args)
```

Or

```
/** Calls `f` with args and returns its result. Before returning the 
* value, it invokes onCompleted(t), where `t` is the time spent in `f`.
*/
template<class OnCompleted, class Function, class... T>
auto timedCall(OnCompleted&& on_completed, Function&& f, T&&... args)
```

Or even

```
/** Calls `f` with args. When the function returns, `on_completed(t, std::move(res))`
* is called, where `t` is the time spent in `f`, and `res` is its return value.
*/
template<class OnCompleted, class Function, class... T>
void timedCall(OnCompleted&& on_completed, Function&& f, T&&... args)
```

Note: The degenerate case of `f(args...)` being void is ommited for brevity.

Another note: One could hardcode a printout to stderr before timedCall returns the value, but it is good to have the option do something else with the time measurement. For the last two, which is the correct order of `f` and `on_completed`.

Comment: What use case do you see for the last two functions? Since you (probably) want your functions to run synchronously, why would you pass a callback? Just asking to see if there is something I missed.

Comment: Personally I like the first case.

Comment: @Victor, apparently, the second version is to enable, e.g., to print out the time that the function has spent. So for general usability the second version seems to be to go, but I like the first version the best.

Comment: As for the correct order of `f` and `on_completed`, I would certainly say that `on_completed` must be the last argument. This would make passing lambdas _much_ more readable.

Comment: @jvd Unfortunately that can be a bit of a mess on some compilers (particularly older ones), when you're putting such a parameter after a parameter pack

Comment: Yeah, I fully understand that. But that's the joy of library development, no? :-)

Comment: No, not at all :P

Comment: If this `timedCall` is used in debug mode but not in release mode (i.e. not measuring at all) then you need that the returned value is that of `f` call. That makes only option 2 doable.

Comment: @Ripi2 This was my problem with the first version, though in this case, I think it is ok to leave it on in release mode. I want  to be able to use the function return value directly, but it is horrible with the extra callback. The problem is related to exception side channel. Maybe I should have a look into the "expected" proposal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that option 2, with the addition of passing the result as reference-to-const, is the most useful:

- It gives you the return value back, so it can be used directly
- The notification callback can use the result to print something like

  `"Processed %zu entries in %.7f seconds\n"`

  For for different return types, it is possible to use a function object with multiple overloads for `operator()()`